# DIV Layout Issue

Tags: css, layout, html

I am having cross-browser trouble with a DIV layout on the following page:

[www.richmindonline.com/index2.html](http://www.richmindonline.com/index2.html)

I have created a border around both the divs to make it easy to identify.

It appears that IE9 is nesting the inner DIV correctly within the outer DIV, whereas Firefox is separating the divs differently.  I am using a "cheat"  tag in order to align the divs to center, but I test without those tags and the browsers still render them differently.

The divs in question are located under my comment line:

I know you guys are smart, and I'm looking for your help!  Thanks, Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear floated divs by adding something like: `<br clear="all"/>` or `<div style="clear:both; height:0;"></div>` and add a width to the parent div, this should fix it.

More info: A common problem with float-based layouts is that the floats' container doesn't want to stretch up to accomodate the floats. If you want to add, say, a border around all floats (ie. a border around the container) you'll have to command the browsers somehow to stretch up the container all the way.

e.g.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div style="float:left"></div>
  <div style="float:left"></div>
  <div style="float:left"></div>
  <br clear="all"/>
</div>
```

For more information: http://quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: Hi Reina, I don't quite understand where to add this code, and I already have a width assigned to the parent DIV, at least I think.  Any clarification would be helpful.  Thanks, Rob

Comment: Add it just after the last div before closing the parent/container div

Comment: Ok....just tried it and nothing.  I think I'm not understanding which div is the "last" and which one is the "parent".  There are so many divs on this page that I'm confused.  I'm sorry.  Maybe you could show me an example from my code?

Comment: Ok, Reina.  I took a chance and placed it in another spot and it worked.  Can you just explain what this tag does?  What does the "Clear" mean?